# Where do I find out when a pycharm python file was made?

Tags: macos, file, pycharm

If there is no way to find out is there any way to find out when a file was first created on a Mac?

Comment: File system attributes? Are you asking when a file sitting on your disk was created?

Answer (score 0):

Mac shows the created time when you select a file in Finder. Almost always editors depend on os provided attributes for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to determine this, and for any file in OSX.

---

The first option works if you are familiar with Terminal and navigation in Unix (Bash etc on OSX).  Use the list files "ls" command.

Navigate to the folder your pycharm python file is contained in. Use the ls command to list the contents of that folder (directory) and include the options t,r and U.

For example:

```
ls -alhtrU
```

This instructs the ls command to list:

- "a" both visible and invisible files in the directory,
- "l" in long (single column down the page) format,
- "h" with human readable file sizes,
- "t" listed in order of time modified/last accessed/created,
- "r" in reverse so most recently created file is at the bottom of the list and hence visible if the list is long as nearest to your command prompt. Finally add the
- "U" directing the ls command to use the date the file was
  created as the time information for ordering and displaying the
  files.

This method is not perfect. If the file was created last calendar year, only the year is displayed. If the file was created this calendar year, the created date and time to the minute is displayed. If you include an r in the ls command as suggested, the most recently created files appear in the ls list at the bottom (reverse order). This is helpful if there are many files in that folder/directory and your files of interest were created recently compared to the other files in that directory.

There is likely a different unix command to show the creation date and time of the particular file your interested in.

Learning the options available for basic Unix commands can be very helpful. This and other options for the ls command can be found by entering in Terminal.

```
man ls
```

This gives you the manual page for the ls command. Press "q" to exit when your finished reading to return to the Terminal command line. Or open a second Terminal window to load man pages so that you can reference your options in one terminal window while practicing them in the command line in another.

---

The second option is to open the folder the file your interested in sits in, in the OSX GUI.

Open the folder, then go to the Finder Menu, under View, select View Options. You can tick the box to show file "Date Created".

This solution saves you the time required to learn more about the ls Unix command and has the benefit of a real time update as you create new files in that folder, which may be desirable. However, as downside, if your interested in invisible files (begin with a "." as shown in ls command in Terminal), then these will not be visible without additional OSX tweaks. An alternative here is using Finder, Find, for that folder specifically and using the more detailed options available in Find.